# Anonymous FTP login doesn't work on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, ftp, iis

I set up a local FTP server using IIS and enabled anonymous login. However I still can't log in as anonymous/myemail@gmail.com; it says it's the wrong username/password. How is this possible? I also tried setting up authenticated login but I have no idea where to create user accounts for that...

Comment: Have you granted authorization to "all users" (authentication != authorization)?

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: open inetmgr -> select your ftp site on the left pane -> click ftp authorization rules in middle pane and check that there is a like "allow" "all users" "read write"

Comment: Tried that, didn't seem to work. Still booted back to login every time I try to log in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My anonymous FTP login was bound to my Windows login, but it appears that I'd mistyped the password for my Windows login when configuring the FTP login. Oops!